# Unique issue! Range.End.Row works in one workbook, but not another

Tags: vba, excel

I was beginning to gather data for a weekly average from one workbook when I realized that another workbook had daily averages instead of values by shift. (There are three shifts where I work.) I realized that it would be much faster to just use the daily average since that would require me to process 1/3 the data.

I went to use most of the code that I had started using for the first workbook for the second workbook. I changed arguments where necessary. I used:

```
Workbooks(2ndWB).Worksheets("Daily").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

As I had before and many other times in this project to find the last row...only this time it failed. It says type mismatch. I have tried every numerical variable, I've tried variant, and I've tried range, but the error persists. I've tried to use Debug.Print to see what this line is trying to spit out to no avail.

The way I see it, there is really only one difference:

Initially:
Code executed in WB 1 counted rows in WB 1.

Now:
Code executed in WB 1 counted rows in WB 2.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thank you

Comment: Workbook object referencing the 2nd workbook.

Comment: In that case it's just `2ndWB.Worksheets("Daily")` and not `Workbooks(2ndWB).Worksheets("Daily")`

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use `dim 2ndwb as Workbook` since a var cannot start with a number. If you can get that figured out then use `2ndWB.Worksheets("Daily").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` or `Workbooks(2ndWB.Name).Worksheets("Daily").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row `.

Comment: Please read [ALWAYS use Option Explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit).

Comment: Aside from what Jeeped has already pointed out, Is the second workbook open when you run this?

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped. I have those settings turned on, this was just a simple case of my brain shutting off temporarily. See the answer I added.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks @Rory.

I have been working on this project for the last three weeks now and I guess my brain just shut off temporarily. The actual reference isn't 2ndWB (I just used that to make it easier to see the problem.) The actual reference was reportwb. BUT, as Rory pointed out, this is a simple case of me essentially saying    `Workbooks(Workbooks("reportwb")).Worksheets...`

That is obviously wrong. Thank you all for your quick help. If there was another person in the office that knew anything about vba this probably wouldn't have made it here, but nevertheless, thank you for helping me see my brain fart!

Comment: Also a good idea to specify your intended worksheet to perform `Rows.Count` on